# Java limit CPU when run tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-speed

I using server AWS EC2, install server tomcat 8, java 1.7

I using Munin and VisualVM remote tomcat for test speed. But in Munin CPU is good and in VisualVM CPU 90%-100%.

I think maybe java limit CPU for tomcat.

How I can increase CPU for tomcat?

This result VisualVM
[image]

This result Munin
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by increase CPU for tomcat?. Because if your application requires resources from Tomcat, or if it is that busy, automatically the usage will go up. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You can see in Munin log. My CPU only using max 20%-25%. Why in VisualVM CPU for tomcat is 90% - 100%. Why CPU tomcat don't using CPU more in server?

Answer (score 1):

Munin timeline scale is +/- 10 times larger than the visual VM one. It should explain why the Munin CPU usage mean is lower than the VisualVM one

Answer (score 0):

Java does not limit the CPU usage of a process. Your load test doesn't appear to be stressing your server very much...